# Cant update the database with this string what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c#, mysql

Here is the code, can anyone help me?

```
Value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

switch (Value)
{
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter number");
        number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
         Console.WriteLine("Please insert the first word");
        word1 = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please insert the second word");
        word2 = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        string sql1 = "INSERT INTO storage ('" + number + "', '" + word1 + "', '" + word2 + "')";


        one.Update(sql1);


        break;
```

Comment: its what i call my class like SimpleDataScource one = new SimpleDataScource

Comment: Why are people voting this down?

Comment: @Mr.Bean maybe cuz of incomplete information like data types of number, word1, word2....what is the exception...

Comment: @Mr.Bean btw your INSERT statement must have field values names to insert into

Comment: You missed VALUES in sql INSERT try `string sql1 = "INSERT INTO storage VALUES ('" + number + "', '" + word1 + "', '" + word2 + "')";`

Comment: @Where is the update statement

Comment: @Mr.Bean where you write the update statement

Comment: So man wrongs ins a single line : not using parameters, wrong syntax, not declaring field names is a bad practice,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would solve this following way:

replace

```
string sql1 = "INSERT INTO storage ('" + number + "', '" + word1 + "', '" + word2 + "')";
one.Update(sql1);
```

with

```
string sCommand = "INSERT INTO storage (@number, @word1, @word2)";
using (MySqlConnection mConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    mConnection.Open();
    using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand(sCommand, mConnection))
    {
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@number", number));
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@word1", word1));
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@word2", word2));
        myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

...or give some more information about your SimpleDataScource-Object